# Mathematical name of this type of graph

Tags: graph-theory

If you have a tree that also might merge branches, but only in a directed way, i.e. all edges are one step either towards or away from the "root", what can we call it? It's a special case of a directed graph.

Version control systems with branches such as git have these graph structures. In git you have the forward/backward in time (with the epoch as the "root") with the possibility of branches being merged.

Example from the git page on wikipedia, 1 being the "root":
[image: git-graph from the git-page on wikipedia]
( https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Revision_controlled_project_visualization-2010-24-02.svg )

Comment: I feel like this question is sort of the inverse of the article [Git for Computer Scientists](http://eagain.net/articles/git-for-computer-scientists/): a "quick introduction to git internals for people who are not scared by words like Directed Acyclic Graph."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as a [directed acyclic graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph). For this type of graph no path along the directed edges can meet itself again at another point, but different paths could possibly diverge and then merge again.

[Section 3.5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph#Genealogy_and_version_history) in the same article linked above actually mentions version control systems.

Comment: even if it only has one top-level node?

Comment: @FilipHaglund The situation where there is only one top-level node is a special case. If it were a tree we would say that it is "rooted." I suppose the same term could be applied to directed acyclic graphs.